# Force 1/3 width window in Windows 10 Tablet Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

In Tablet Mode, activating my window causes it to get full width, but our software is a utility program that really works with other programs and needs 1/3 to 1/4 width. Can I control how wide the window gets and also force sharing with the last app?

Comment: MVVM or code-behind?

Comment: How about code-behind

Answer (score 0):

Try to use properties `System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth` and `System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight` which gets size `Width` and `Height` of display in pixels.

```
if (System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth < 1500 && 
    System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight < 800)//you should set your own parameters of your Window of Tablet
{                
   Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = Application.Current.MainWindow.Height/3;
   Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width/2;
}
```